# CakePHP: Sending Logging output via Email if at least 1 error occured

Tags: cakephp

I have a console application based on CakePHP 3.6. It should email automatically as soon as the logging includes at least one error or warning. Are there Loggers made for this?

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find any, I created a custom logger that saves the log entries in a class variable:

```
<?php
namespace App\Log\Engine;
use Psr\Log\LogLevel;

use Cake\Log\Engine\BaseLog;

class BufferLog extends BaseLog
{
    protected static $buffer = '';

    protected static $needsSending = false;

    public static function getBuffer() {
        if (self::$needsSending)
            return self::$buffer;
        return '';
    }

    public static function reset() {
            self::$buffer = false;
            self::$needsSending = false;
    }

    public function log($level, $message, array $context = [])
    {
        $alert = [
            LogLevel::EMERGENCY,
            LogLevel::CRITICAL,
            LogLevel::ALERT,
            LogLevel::ERROR,
            LogLevel::WARNING,
        ];
        if (in_array($level, $alert)) {
            self::$needsSending = true;
        }

        $message = $this->_format($message);

        unset($context['scope']);
        if ($context) {
            $message .= "\n" . $this->_format($context) . "\n";
        }

        self::$buffer .=  date('c') . ' [' . $level . '] ' . $message . "\n";
    }
}
```

Then, at the end of what the shell `Command` does, it sends an email if needed:

```
$logOutput = BufferLog::getBuffer();
if ($logOutput) {
    Email::deliver('you@example.com', 'Log', $logOutput, ['from' => 'me@example.com']);
}
```

(Note that this will only work for errors in the log file, not for PHP errors.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log PHP errors, there is a plugin for that:

https://github.com/ebrigham1/cakephp-error-email